# Javascript при событии onclick изменяются два разных Id

Tags: ajax, javascript

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на ссылку, менялась картинка и описание. Они надятся в разных id и далеко друг от друга на странице. 
Например если использовать такую функцию, то менятся будет один и с одними данными. А нужно чтобы данные брались с двух разных скрипов и вставлялись в разные места.

```
function getColorList(id, type, desc, link)
{
    jQuery.ajax({url: "/catalog/colors.php",
        dataType: "html",
        type: "GET",
        data: { c: id, types: type, desc: desc},
        success: function(msg) {
            //alert(msg);
            document.getElementById('colCont').innerHTML = msg;
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //alert('Ошибка');
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var elements = new Array('id1','id2','id3');
for(idAttr in elements){
 element = document.getElementById(idAttr);
 element.onclick = function(id, type, desc, link){
  getColorList(id, type, desc, link);
 }
}
```

Comment: а на стороне сервера как это распределить по id?

Comment: Из `c: id, types` будет извлекаться

Comment: А не могли бы полностью написать включая то что я написал, я не пойму как это вообще будет выглядеть, куда вставлять то, что вы написали.